# Specific symbol and the Strings file

Tags: objective-c, string, xcode, symbols

So I have a symbol: π in the strings file and it turnes out that due to it I cannot successfuly compile to fatal:

Copy EN.strings
Command /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copystrings failed with exit code 1

If I remove π it's fine. The strange thing is that even if I put π in the comment it still won't compile.

what to do?
Thankx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find the Unicode value of the character, you could escape it in the following manor:

```
NSString *str = @"\u00F6"
```

And Java (just for comparison):

```
String str = "\u00F6";
```

Although I'd imagine that the compile issue relates to the character being from a different encoding to the specified encoding of your source file. I believe the compiler will interpret your source as UTF-8 by default.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your strings file is using a Unicode encoding, and make sure the string is quoted; this has solved the issue for me in the past.